# Clipping Mask Problem In Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration, clipping-mask

[image: Clipping mask problem]

I am trying to draw a wall with street light above it.

The light is the triangle with 4 corners. I'm trying to clip mask the bricks and triangle but the bricks don't show. They are there when I hover over the triangle but are not visible.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  All I can say is make sure your bricks are in a group, and the red triangle is above the bricks. Then select both, and apply the clipping mask.

Comment: Did you get solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to **put 2nd triangle layer on top bricks group**.

Follow this pattern. It will help you.

1) Take triangle shape.

2) Paste your bricks above it. make all in 1 group.

3) Take triangle shape again.this is mask layer.

[image]

4) Select 2nd triangle shape and group of bricks.

[image]

5) Right click select "**make clipping mask**".

[image]